# TD Hover will not work

Tags: html, css, hover, html-table

I have the following CSS:

```
        td: hover {
        background-color:red;
        }



        td {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
        }
```

and my HTML is just:

```
<table>
<tr><td> </td></tr>
</table>
```

I can't get the `hover` to work. Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:hover` is a pseudo-selector, and everything beginning with `:` is such (e.g. `:active`, `:before` etc.).

This can be confused with specifying values:

```
something: value;
```

So you need to think about pseudo-selectors as separate objects, not a value.

That's why you need to fix your `td: hover` so it looks like `td:hover`.

Note that if you put a space after `td` like so:

```
td :hover { ...
```

This is equal to:

```
td: *:hover { ...
```

and therefore will select all items descending from `td` and apply a style on hover to them ([see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/w46Ac/)).

Remember, spaces have a meaning in CSS.

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the space before `:hover`:

```
td:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the space between `td :hover` as the `<td>` has no [descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) ..

`td:hover` will work

http://jsfiddle.net/xwYTa/